# WHat should be the format of the solution for this Homogeneous System?

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the solutions to homogeneous system $$(4I{3}-A)B = 0$$

A = $\begin{bmatrix}2 & 4 & 1\\0 & 2 & 3\\0 & 0 & 4\end{bmatrix}$

B =  $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$

I'm confused on the format when I substitute A and B to the given homogeneous system.

Is this correct?

(4$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 &0\\0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ - $\begin{bmatrix}2 & 4 & 1\\0 & 2 & 3\\0 & 0 & 4\end{bmatrix}$) * $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$ = 0

Or am I supposed to make B matrix  $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 &0\\0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: Your first write-up is correct, $B$ is a $3\times 1$ matrix.

Comment: Thank you! sorry but am I really just supposed to multiply $\begin{bmatrix}2 & -4 & -1\\0 & 2 &-3\\0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ with $\begin{bmatrix}x \\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: Yes, you are supposed to get the equivalent of a system of equations $2x-4y-z=0$, $2y-3z=0$ and $0=0$.

Comment: Though you are presumably meant to find the solution of the system by manipulating the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}2 & -4 & -1\\0 & 2 & -3\\0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ via Gaussian elimination into a reduced row echelon form.

Comment: What does $4I3$ mean?

Comment: Thank you Randy!      4I3 is 4 multiplied by Identity matrix 3

Comment: Ah, so, when you write I3, you really mean $I_3$. You should have a look at the suggestions for formatting mathematics on this site. You can get there via the Help menu.

Comment: Thank you! I'll do that :)